Ha'azinu as a spiritual remedy for heretical thoughts
The B'nei Yissoschor in the sefer Agra D'Pirka, as quoted by the sefer Kavod Shabbos (Parshas Ha'azinu, p. 548) says:

לומר בכל יום שירת האזינו: נראה לי בסגולה ללמוד בכל יום שירת האזינו,
והוא סגולה להנצל מאפיקורסות ומדעות הכוזביות
To recite the Song of
Ha'azinu every day: It seems to me to be a worthwhile practice to
study the Song of Haazinu every day, as it is a spiritual remedy
(segulah) to be saved from heresy and false beliefs.

See also the Steipler Gaon in Kiryana D'Igarta (Vol. 1, letter 45):

I have also seen it brought in holy books that reciting the Song of Ha'azinu every day greatly dispels thoughts of heresy [though, of course, not immediately but over time]. Many years ago, someone came to me, lamenting about thoughts of heresy, heaven forbid. I told him what is mentioned in the holy books about reciting the Song of Ha'azinu, and he did so for several consecutive years. He later informed me that he was completely saved from these thoughts. May G-d help us for the sake of His Name.

What exactly is it about the Shir Ha'azinu that dispells heretical thoughts from a person? Are there any meforshim or sources that discuss this? Why especially Ha'azinu?

How does someone know they need to be saved from false beliefs? Wouldn't that belief inherently destroy something as a false belief?

@dude sometimes a person does not know what is right and wrong, only when they keep Torah and listen to G-d. So maybe, the Bnei Yissoschor talks about someone who is off the derech?

that makes sense in regards to a person's actions if they are struggling in life but when it comes to beliefs themselves I find it hard to understand. Once someone becomes aware that a particular belief is false then I would think they they would stop believing in it and if they don't come to realize that it's false then why would they do something to rid themselves of the beliefs. I could simply be misunderstanding something here though

Yes, agree. But I think that is what the Bnei Yissoschor means, that by studying the song of Ha'azinu, that core-belief is strengthened again. Remains the question: why this song?
